# React nested custom propType

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a custom Todo propType  :

```
    export const TodoPropType = PropTypes.shape({
     title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     description: PropTypes.string
   })
```

And I have my collection of Todo like this

```
{
 "Kfd455gdf4gdf" : { // key as uid
    title: "blabla",
    description: "blobloblo"
  },
  "Kf65sd465fsd" : {
     title: "blabla2",
     description: "blobloblo2"
  }
}
```

I would like to do a custom propType to validate the collection and reuse my Todo propType

```
 export const TodosPropType = function(props, propName, componentName) {
  const todos = props[propName]

 // ... valide that an object..

  Object.keys(todos).map((qid) => {

    // valide that the qid is a string

    // reuse my TodoPropType 
  })
}
```

But It's deprecated to manualy call a PropType. I got a warning :

> Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `todos` prop on `TodoComponement`. This is deprecated and will not work in production with the next major versi....

How do you deal with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately with that deprecation you would need to use `typeof stringToCheck === 'string'` and manually check that `props.title` existed. If either of those things were missing you'd then manually return an error using `new Error('error goes here')`

We have similar thigns in our app and never have to do custom validation why can't you do something like this.

```
component.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.objectOf(TodoPropType)   
}
```

this will tell the component to check if todos are an array and if so the content of the array should be the given shape and if any doesn't match that shape then it will throw an error.

Comment: It was what I did before using Firebase.
They don't use array but Object with key as uid (as I said in my post)
What I would need is a propType that validate it's an object with one or multiple key string with TodoPropType for value.

Comment: then you should check out `objectOf` which is what you are looking for. Its basically `arrayOf` but for an object whose keys should have certain values.